# Rewrite all urls change aspx extension to html

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm new in the iis url rewrite module and i not how to do this.

for example i have this url:

```
http://localhost/section.aspx?x=section1&IDSection=45
```

And i want this:

```
http://localhost/section~x~section11~IDSection~45.html
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can I suggest using [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) and have a url like `http://localhost/section/1/45`

Comment: My urls are already well positioned in this format and if i change, this could affect my ranking.

The question is because i migrated from iis6 to iis7.

Comment: replacing a question mark `(?)` with a tilde `(~)` doesn't really make your query strings all that much prettier. In fact, I'd argue that it's even less intuitive. Not only that, but ANY way you change your url string, you're affecting ranking.

Comment: I also prefer http://localhost/section/1/45, i try to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution using URL Rewrite module in IIS7:

- Create new blank inbound rule
- The patterns is: ^section~x~([_0-9a-z-]+)~IDSection~([0-9]+).html
- The rewrite action: Section.aspx?x={R:1}&IDSection={R:2}
- Create new black outbund rule
- Create new precondition with the next format:

  - Condition input: {RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}
  - Pattern: ^text/html
- The pattern is: ^Section.aspx\?x=([_0-9a-z-]+)(?:&|&)IDSection=([0-9]+)$
- And the rewrite action: Section~x~{R:2}~IDSection~{R:2}.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is write a handler.  That way you can capture the extension and then parse it as needed.  This will be invisible to the user.
Handler is definitely the way you want to go as if you use URL Routing, you will still need to change the handler from aspx to html in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in c# to use a customized extension in your URL in ASP.NET.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
    if (app.Request.Path.ToLower().IndexOf(".html") > 0)
    {
        string rawpath = app.Request.Path;
        string path = rawpath.Substring(0, rawpath.IndexOf(".html"));
        app.Context.RewritePath(path+".aspx");
    }
}
```